# How to implement such design (circles with radius more then screen width) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to make a circle with radius bigger than screen width as set in picture?
design:

[image]

I tried to set width of container bigger than screen width, but nothing happened. Any idea how to implement this? I will be very grateful if you help me.

Comment: Get the width of the screen using `MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width` and then add as much size as you want.

Comment: For Example, you can get 150% width of the screen using : `MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width *1.5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a circle that overflows out of the screen from the `center` by using the [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Code:

```
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double scrWidth = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width;
    double scrHeight = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height;
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          width: scrWidth,
          height: scrHeight,
          color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.8),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              Positioned(
                width: scrWidth * 1.8,
                height: scrHeight * 1.8,
                child: Container(
                  width: scrWidth,
                  height: scrHeight,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                width: scrWidth * 1.5,
                height: scrHeight * 1.5,
                child: Container(
                  width: scrWidth,
                  height: scrHeight,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.yellow.withOpacity(0.2),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                width: scrWidth * 0.8,
                height: scrHeight * 0.8,
                child: Container(
                  width: scrWidth,
                  height: scrHeight,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think transform widget can help you out , just put your circles inside stack and wrap them with with this widget , it has many properties which you can use .

Comment: your welcome brother , maybe you can mark it useful if you like .